# JQuery filter on data attributes using "not like operator"

Tags: jquery, filter

I am trying to filter options based on the options **not containing** the selected text. "Not" and "containing" work, - just not together.

```
$('#Offices option').filter('[data-faculty!="Europe"]').remove();
// [!] (not) this works - removes all but Europe


$('#Offices option').filter('[data-faculty*="Europe"]').remove();
// [*=] this works - removes all but those options with attributes containing Europe
```

I hoped / assumed a simple "!" addition would work but it doesn't.
`!*=` gives a syntax error. e.g.

```
$('#Offices option').filter('[data-faculty!*="Europe"]').remove();
```

I also tried "not" but I also got syntax errors.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this - "not containing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) function

```
$('#Offices option[data-faculty]').filter(function(){
   return $(this).attr('data-faculty')  !== 'Europe'; 
}).remove();
```

*not containing*

```
$('#Offices option[data-faculty]').filter(function(){
   return $(this).attr('data-faculty').indexOf('Europe') == -1;
}).remove();
```

Comment: `.filter()` is the go-to place if you can't quite find the correct selector to do what you want (or you have some complicated/additional logic to apply) as it moves the logic into plain javascript/jquery.

Comment: Thanks so much Satpal,  this works perfectly. One last question (sorry) - if I was getting the name of the dropdown element in as a variable "dropdown", do you know what syntax I would use to reference it.

Comment: i.e. instead of $('#Offices option[data-faculty]').filter

Comment: Do you mean the `name` or the `id`?  They're not the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the id of the select element.

Comment: @SeamusGormley you just need to create valid selector using string concatenation, for ID selector that's the way

Comment: Yes, got it - eventually! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) in the selector or [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) chained

eg to remove everything *except* containing Europe:

```
$("#offices option:not([data-faculty*='Europe']").remove()

$("#offices option").not("[data-faculty*='Europe']").remove()
```

Comment: Thanks but this did not filter for me?

Comment: Glad you got a working answer - if you'd provided some sample html, I could have double checked that it worked first.